# Invalid Duplicate indentifier 'item'

Tags: typescript

Using typescript 0.9.5 i run into the error message "TS2000: Duplicate indentifier 'item'"

Source code (1 line) -> test.ts:

```
var item;
```

Commandline command:

```
tsc.exe test.ts
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this all your code in test.ts? Only this one line `var item;`? If not please post your whole `test.ts` or at least the part which reproduces the error!

Comment: I know, it seems funny. As a programmer I'm used to developing much more bugs in one file, but in this case ... yeah, just this one line!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the standard `lib.d.ts` already contains a global function named `item` (because [IE has an item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) named method on the window object):

```
declare function item(index: any): any;
```

So if you want to compile your one liner with the global name `item` you need to use the `--noLib` option which disables the automatic `lib.d.ts` loading:

```
tsc.exe test.ts --noLib
```

Of course you can also fix this with not having the global name `item`:

- just rename it to something else if you insist to have it global, but you still can have other name collusion, see the `lib.d.ts` for the globally defined functions
- just don't have a global variable so wrap it function scope (put your `var item;` in a IEF , or a module, etc.)

Comment: ahh... that sounds logical... In vs2013 this 'program' compiles without problem .. does vs2013 use the --noLib flag?

Comment: good question, I don't know which options Vs2013 uses. I've only tried with the tsc.exe and with the node.js tsc compiler.

Comment: @Paul0515 @nemesv Typescript always tries to generate the javascript if it can even if the compile fails. I am sure the compile is failing for visual studio as well, but you just get the JS. It does not use `noLib`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is as mentioned by nemesrv. However I would suggest *not* creating a variable `item` on the global scope and just wrap your file in module

```
module foo{
   var item; 
   // Other code you have goes here. 
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a robust solution! Cluttering the global scope being a bad thing ...